# Regex match a word, but not surrounded by specific words

Tags: regex

I'm looking for a regex syntax that would allow me to detect a word, but that doesn't it detect if it's surrounded by very specific words.
for example:
the word "beautiful" is detected, if only or in a sentence
BUT
the word "beautiful" is not detected if it's surrounded by the words "this" and "picture". For example: "I love this beautiful picture".

Thank you for your help

Comment: Try negative lookbehind and negative lookahead, example: https://regex101.com/r/P7HtEj/1

Comment: Regex questions without attemps are considered off-topic. Please show us what you tried.

Comment: @InSync, what is the source for your assertion? The only related policy I'm aware of is that askers of questions that are homework problems must provide evidence (not necessarily code) that they have attempted to solve the problem.

Comment: @CarySwoveland See [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76408390#comment134734299_76408390).

Comment: @InSync, I believe all you can say is that some Stack Exchange members believe that questions that do not provide evidence that the asker has attempted to solve the problem are "off-topic". Moreover, I take discussions at Meta with a grain of salt. The few times I've been there I've found it a very unwelcoming place, and certainly not representative of the community as a whole. When it comes to matters of SO policy I confine my attention to SO's [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understood the question to mean that the word should be found unless it is surrounded by both of the other words, and also that the surrounding words should match exactly. This makes the regex slightly more complicated than the one in dinhit's comment, but I agree that negative lookbehinds and negative lookaheads are the key. We just need an "or" to finish it off, and the [^\w] terms to exclude other word characters in the surrounding words.

```
(?<!\bthis )\bbeautiful\b|\bbeautiful\b(?! picture\b)
```

Try it out here: https://regex101.com/r/GzuVln/2

Comment: Why escape spaces?

Comment: I suggest you modify you regex to: `(?<!\bthis )beautiful\b|\bbeautiful(?! picture\b)`. 1) there is no need for capture groups; 2) the space character need not be escaped; 3) `[^\w]` prevents 'this' from being at the beginning of the string or 'picture' from being at the end of the string, so replace both with word boundaries (`\b`); 4) the first `beautiful` should be followed by a word boundary (to avoid matching 'beautifully') and the second `beautiful` should be preceded by a word boundary (to avoid matching 'unbeautiful', a word I frequently use in Scrabble) .

Comment: thank you Cary and Caleb, for the help. Cary your regex is pretty good. tested and approved