# How do I return 3 characters either side of a null byte in Elixir?

Tags: null, binary, elixir, pattern-matching, byte

If I have a string, for example, `hello this isa<<0>>string.`, how do I return the three characters either side of the null byte, including the null byte, e.g., `isa<<0>>str`?

I was trying something like:

```
~r/(?<=.{0,2})(.{3}).*?<<0>>(.{3})(?=.{0,2})/
```

Comment: Could use `(?:[a-z]\s*){3}<<0>>(?:\s*[a-z]){3}` https://regex101.com/r/KNdvZt/1

Comment: Apologies, I have added what I have tried in the comment above. I am not sure if the presence of a null value is causing issues when matching? 

@sln when I try and use that code I get an empty %{} returned. 

For example:
regex = ~r/(?:[a-z]\s*){3}p(?:\s*[a-z]){3}/ 
string = "Hello my name is<<0>>a string"
Regex.named_captures(regex, string) 

I get %{} returned

Comment: There are no captures (named or not) in the regex. Just the overall match, which every language records (no exceptions). But if you expected to see a match and there was none, check the syntax documentation of the regex engine your language uses vs the regex provided.

Comment: I presume `<<0>>` is not really the character code 0. If so then the regex is `(?:[a-z]\s*){3}\x00(?:\s*[a-z]){3}`

Comment: Btw `(?<=.{0,2})` is a variable length lookbehind. Currently only Dot-net style engines can do that.

Comment: Doing this with a regexp in [tag:elixir] is counter-idiomatic. See my answer for the proper solution.

Comment: Hi @l288, what are you actually trying to do? Why do you need the 3 characters around the null byte?

Answer (score 3):

In [Elixir](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/elixir), one does not need regexp to do that. Recursion would work better and faster (and way more readable).

```elixir
defmodule NullByte do
  def get_3_around(""),
    do: ""
  def get_3_around(<<pre::binary-size(3), 0, post::binary-size(3), _::binary>>),
    do: pre <> <<0>> <> post
  def get_3_around(<<pre::binary-size(3), 0, post::binary>>),
    do: pre <> <<0>> <> post
  def get_3_around(<<_::binary-size(1), rest::binary>>),
    do: get_3_around(rest)

  def test, do: get_3_around("hello this is a " <> <<0>> <> "string")
end
```

Comment: Nice use of Elixir's binary parsing sir!

Answer (score 0):

Strings in Elixir employ the UTF-8 encoding, which means a single character can be longer than one byte, so it's better to design the function to handle UTF-8 characters.  Three characters could be up to 12 bytes long, so rather than assuming every character is 1 byte long, you can match a single UTF-8 character using `var_name::utf8`.  Unfortunately, you are not able to specify a size with the `utf8` type in a binary, so you ***can't*** match multiple UTF-8 characters by simply writing `var_name::utf8-size(3)`, instead you have to explicitly write out three different "segments" (which is a complete pain in the ass, and it's an oversight in the language that should be corrected), for example:

```
<<char1::utf8, char2::utf8, char3::utf8, ....>
```

Next, a null byte is a non-printing character, and elixir won't print a null byte as `<<0>>`.  However, you can explicitly print the string "<<0>>", e.g.

```
IO.iex(7)> IO.puts "<<0>>"
<<0>>
```

But, you should be aware that "<<0>>" is 5 bytes long--not 1 byte.

In the following example, the binary syntax will look up the UTF-8 integer character codes for each character between the double quotes:

```
iex(17)> str = <<"123"::utf8, 0::utf8, "456"::utf8>>
<<49, 50, 51, 0, 52, 53, 54>>

iex(13)> IO.puts str
123^@456   <--shell uses "carrot notation" to display non printing chars
:ok

iex(14)> IO.inspect str
<<49, 50, 51, 0, 52, 53, 54>>
<<49, 50, 51, 0, 52, 53, 54>>
```

If a string/binary contains non-printing characters, then elixir won't output strings in double quote format:

```
iex(2)> IO.inspect <<97,98>>
"ab"
"ab"

iex(3)> IO.inspect <<97, 0, 98>>
<<97, 0, 98>>
<<97, 0, 98>>
```

Here's how to match UTF-8 characters in Elixir:

```
defmodule My do

  #Look for match starting at beginning of string:

  def grab_3_chars_either_side_of_null(<<char1::utf8,
                                         char2::utf8,
                                         char3::utf8,
                                         0::utf8,   #Tries to match a null byte
                                         char4::utf8,
                                         char5::utf8,
                                         char6::utf8,
                                         _rest::binary>>
                                      ) do



     <<char1::utf8, char2::utf8, char3::utf8,
       "<<0>>",   # Your desired output, which is 5 bytes long.
                  # Change to 0::utf8 if you only want one byte
       char4::utf8, char5::utf8, char6::utf8>>
  end

  #If a match isn't found at the beginning of the string above,
  #then drop the first UTF-8 character, `_::utf8`, and look for a match at
  #start of the rest of the string (the recursive function call):

  def grab_3_chars_either_side_of_null(<<_::utf8,
                                         rest::binary>>
                                   ) do

    grab_3_chars_either_side_of_null(rest)
  end

end

#If all the UTF-8 characters have been dropped off the front of the string,
#then the string is empty, and no matches were found, so return the atom
#`:no_match`:

def grab_3_chars_either_side_of_null(<<>>), do: :no_match
```

I'll leave it as an exercise to define other branches of `grab_3_chars_either_side_of_null/1` as you see fit.

Note:

1. char1, char2, etc. will actually be assigned integers, and in order to convert an integer back to a UTF-8 character in a string, you have to write `<<char1::utf8>>`.
2. `rest::binary` is like a greedy `.*` in a regex: it will match 0 to an infinite number of characters, and it can only be placed at the end of a binary.

If all that is too confusing, you could also use [String.split/3](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/1.12/String.html#split/3) to split on the null byte, then use [String.split_at/2](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/1.12/String.html#split/3) on each piece to get the last three characters (-3) of the first piece and the first three characters (3) of the second piece.

Answer (score 0):

This is a simplification of Aleksei's answer, modified to return a 2-tuple.

```elixir
defmodule NullByte do
  def get_3_around(<<>>), do: nil
  def get_3_around(<<pre::binary-3, 0, post::binary-3, _::binary>>), do: {pre, post}
  def get_3_around(<<_::binary-1, rest::binary>>), do: get_3_around(rest)
end
```

Usage:

```elixir
iex(1)> NullByte.get_3_around("aaa" <> <<0>> <> "bbb")
{"aaa", "bbb"}
iex(2)> NullByte.get_3_around("aaabbb" <> <<0>> <> "cccddd")
{"bbb", "ccc"}
iex(3)> NullByte.get_3_around("aaa" <> <<0>> <> "b")
nil
iex(4)> NullByte.get_3_around("foo")
nil
```